# Post text message on facebook wall

Tags: android, facebook, post, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-requests

I got a problem while posting text message on the wall.
I expected the apps will login to fb and post a text message on the wall, but nothing is posted on my wall.

The following is my code
The login part is the same as the Facebook guide and i just added the permission "publish stream"

```
public class FB_trial extends Activity {
Facebook facebook = new Facebook("app_id");
private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);  
private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fb_trial);
    /*
     * The following is tutorial sample code
     */
    mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
    long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);
    if(access_token != null) {
        facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
    }
    if(expires != 0) {
        facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
    }

    /*
     * Only call authorize if the access_token has expired.
     */
    if(!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        facebook.authorize(this, new String[] {"publish_stream"}, new DialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                editor.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
                editor.putLong("access_expires", facebook.getAccessExpires());
                editor.commit();
            }
            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}
            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {}
            @Override
            public void onCancel() {}
        });
    }
    //end of the login sample code

    //post wall fx
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("message", "Fb testing message");
    params.putString("access_token", access_token);
    mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
    mAsyncRunner.request("me/feed", params, "POST", new RequestListener(){
        @Override
        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
            System.out.println("post wall success");
        }
        @Override
        public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {}
        @Override
        public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                Object state) {}
        @Override
        public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                Object state) {}
        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {}
    }, null);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_fb_trial, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

}

The "wall post success" message is shown in the log (is that means the request is complete?)
but i can't find the post on my wall.

Comment: tag facebook in your LOGCAT browser and provide the text!

Comment: you have add your `hash Key` in your Facebook App?

Comment: I have Use the Keytool and type the hash key to the Facebook app dashbroad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the dialog to post to wall:

```
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("link", linkgame);
        params.putString("name", subject);
        params.putString("description", content);
        params.putString("picture", iconUrl);

        facebook.dialog(((Activity) ctx).getParent(), "feed", params,
                new DialogListener() {

                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    }

                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}
                    public void onError(DialogError e) {}
                    public void onCancel() {}
        });
```